# R Shiny download .RData

Tags: r, shiny

How can I allow the user of a shiny app to download the `.RData` of a reactive?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  downloadButton("dl", "Download")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  react <- reactive(mtcars)

  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data.RData")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      save(react(), file = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The above errors:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5473
Warning: Error in save: object ‘react()’ not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Edited the question, now shows error.

Comment: Ah ok. `save` searches the object named `react()`, and there's no such object. In the `content` function, you could do `dat <- react()` and then `save(dat, file=file)`.

Comment: Indeed, that works, thanks!